# PixHawk or Naza M V2 for Aerial Imaging of Small Study Area with Hexacopter

Tags: gps, uav, radio-control

I have a project that is going to involve capturing ~80 images of a 35m x 50m agricultural study area for image processing.

I am wondering whether to use a NAZA v2 or PixHawk controller to outfit my ship (on a DJI F550 Flamewheel airframe).

My understanding is that Naza is limited as far as the amount of waypoints I can have during a particular mission. Can I break my imaging mission up into 8 or 10 sub-missions?

I also understand that PixHawk is in many ways superior but getting it up and running can be more finicky - I am on a limited time frame for this project.

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* monkeyshines, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.